# scraping javascript stuck because of fs is not defined

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This is my code, trying to create folder and write image in that folder, but getting this error.

> Error: Error [ReferenceError]: fs is not defined

here is my code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

async function scrapeWebsite() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        await page.goto('url of the website');
        await page.click('div[role="button"]');

        await page.evaluate(async () => {
            let count = 0;
            while (count < 1) {
                const items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a[title]');

                for (const item of items) {
                    count++;

                    const brand_element = item.querySelector('img');
                    const brand = {
                        title: brand_element.getAttribute('title'),
                        logoUrl: brand_element.getAttribute('src')
                    }

                    const currentDirectory = 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Project/xxx/Assets';
                    const folderName = brand.title;
                    const folderPath = `${currentDirectory}\\${folderName}`;
                    const imagePath = `${folderPath}\\${brand.title}.jpg`;

                    await fs.mkdir(folderPath, { recursive: true });
                    await fs.writeFile(imagePath, '');
                    
                    if (count >= 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

scrapeWebsite();
```

Comment: You clearly don't have anything exported by `fs/promises` in a path accessible by however you are running this.  You need to provide more details if you expect anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @possum — If that was the case then `require` wouldn't return `undefined`, it would throw an error.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: DO NOT EVER scrape a website without checking/respecting its [robots.txt](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/robots-txt-web-scraping).

Comment: I'm using version 20.8.0

Comment: The issue is not with the require statement. It's that the code within the evaluate function is run on a browser not in node. You have to pass arguments to evaluate and return value to write it to a file after evaluation.

Comment: @possum `fs` doesn't need to be exported, it's a core Node library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Krzysztof's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388846/scraping-javascript-stuck-because-of-fs-is-not-defined/77390036#comment136431242_77388846) correctly identifies the problem and solution. All code in `evaluate` runs in the browser (you can think "developer tools console"), not in Node. There's no `fs` in the browser. Trying to call functions on undefined variables throws a ReferenceError.

Your code isn't complete and runnable and I'm not sure what site you're scraping, so I can't determine if there are other problems and provide fully working code. But the general pattern you can apply involves moving the `fs` calls back to Node, outside of the `evaluate`, and returning a serializable data structure from `evaluate`. Here's a complete, runnable example:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.2.1

const url = "https://example.com";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => ({
    title: document.querySelector("h1").textContent,
    text: document.querySelector("p").textContent,
  }));
  await fs.writeFile("result.json", JSON.stringify(data));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

and a minimal reproduction of the problem:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.evaluate(() => fs.writeFile("x", "y")); // Error [ReferenceError]: fs is not defined
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```